# moondroid/CoverFlow : App Crashes when loading layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, coverflow

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.HomeNavigationActivity">


    <it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        coverflow:coverHeight="200dp"
        coverflow:coverWidth="140dp"
        coverflow:maxScaleFactor="1.5"
        coverflow:reflectionGap="0px"
        coverflow:rotationThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:scalingThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:spacing="0.6" />

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app crashes while loading this layout which contains it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow

When I remove this the activity gets loaded easily without problems.

There was one problem while adding the dependency 
The error is like :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(My App) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-37
>       is also present at [com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-43:19 to override.

I tried adding 'tools:replace="android:label"' to manifest. Then this error was solved. But I am not able to render this layout file in an activity. Help me :(

Comment: Do you define FeatureCoverFlow.java in your project?

Comment: I have added dependency 
compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'

Is this what you are asking ... right?

Comment: post your menifest file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="My App"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

---------------------

</application>